# How to relearn words after a while not reviewing them?

Tags: learning-methods, reacquisition

In short, I went on holiday for a week and didn't review any words and have forgotten at least 60 that weren't in my long term memory. How can I quickly retrieve them?

Comment: How do you usually learn vocabulary?

Comment: Flashcards, writing sentences with the vocabulary, using them while chatting in the language (I often do this if I learn thematically grouped vocabulary. I just start a conversation about the topic I learnt the vocabulary for). So many ways @ChristopheStrobbe

Answer (score 3):

Although you may not consciously remember them, given that you studied the words well before you went on holiday, your brain will still have stored them in the back of your mind. Therefore, when you try to relearn them now, it will be a much quicker process because you do unconsciously possess the definitions. (There's a psychological effect named for this, but I can't remember it at the moment.)

You should have an easy time remembering the first and last words you studied, thanks to the [serial position effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_position_effect). If you really want to increase the speed at which you relearn the words, try to match the state and mood you were in when you first learned them; through your [mood-congruent memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mood_congruence) and [state-dependent memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-dependent_memory), you should have a much simpler time remembering the words.